# How to break up a function to refer to different "levels" in Python maze game?

Tags: python, file, tkinter, turtle-graphics, maze

I'm using Python 3 and I'm very, very inexperienced so please be kind. I'm trying to make a Python maze game with tkinter and turtle (I know it would be cleaner with just turtle but it is for a project, so I have to use both). 
Basically, under the gold_encounter()
section of my code, I want to break it up so I can have different files (a different set of vocabulary words) for each different level.

I was thinking I could use `if` statements like `if` something `== True:` then I run the `for` loop with the proper file for each individual language, or level. However, nothing I tried using that method worked. Please see my full code below.

```
from turtle import RawTurtle, TurtleScreen
import tkinter
from tkinter import PhotoImage, simpledialog
import random

largefont = ("Verdana", 12)

# Define function to create Spanish level.
def span():
    pen.setup(level_1)
    player.setup(level_1)
    setup(level_1)

# Define function to create French level.
def fren():
    pen.setup(level_2)
    player.setup(level_2)
    setup(level_2)

# Define function to create Japanese level.
def jpn():
    pen.setup(level_3)
    player.setup(level_3)
    setup(level_3)

# Define function to create Turkish level.
def turk():
    pen.setup(level_4)
    player.setup(level_4)
    setup(level_4)

# Create window and canvas using tkinter.
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Language Labyrinth")

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=600, height=600)
canvas.pack()

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
screen.bgcolor('black')

# Define a function to set flag background for Spanish level
def spanishFlag():
    screen.bgpic("spainflag.png")

# Define a function to set flag background for French level
def frenchFlag():
    screen.bgpic("franceflaggrunge.png")

# Define a function to set flag background for Japanese level        
def japaneseFlag():
    screen.bgpic("japanflagoffwhite.png")

# Define a function to set flag background for Turkish level
def turkishFlag():
    screen.bgpic("turkishflagdiagonal.png")

# Define a function to combine the level and background setup functions for Spanish level
def combinedSpanishCommands():
    span()
    spanishFlag()

# Define a function to combine the level and background setup functions for French level
def combinedFrenchCommands():
    fren()
    frenchFlag()

# Define a function to combine the level and background setup functions for Japanese level
def combinedJapaneseCommands():
    jpn()
    japaneseFlag()

# Define a function to combine the level and background setup functions for Turkish level
def combinedTurkishCommands():
    turk()
    turkishFlag()

# Create class with separate window to choose level.
class StartPage():
    def __init__(self):
        # Creation of second window.
        wn = tkinter.Tk()
        wn.title("Welcome!")
        # Creation of game title on start page.
        label = tkinter.Label(wn, text="Language Labyrinth", font=largefont)
        label.pack()

        # Create Spanish level button.
        button = tkinter.Button(wn, text="Spanish", command= combinedSpanishCommands)
        button.pack()

        # Create French level button.
        button2 = tkinter.Button(wn, text="French", command= combinedFrenchCommands)
        button2.pack()

        # Create Japanese level button.
        button3 = tkinter.Button(wn, text="Japanese", command= combinedJapaneseCommands)
        button3.pack()

        # Create Turkish level button.
        button4 = tkinter.Button(wn, text="Turkish", command= combinedTurkishCommands)
        button4.pack()

        # Create quit button for start page.
        qbutton = tkinter.Button(wn, text="Quit", command=wn.destroy)
        qbutton.pack()

start = StartPage()

# Create Pen class to draw the maze.
class Pen(RawTurtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(screen, shape='square')
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.color('white')
        self.penup()

    # Create setup so the maze will be drawn.
    def setup(self, level):
        for y in range(len(level)):
            screen_y = 288 - (y * 24)

            for x in range(len(level[y])):
                if level[y][x] == 'X':
                    screen_x = (x * 24) - 288

                    self.goto(screen_x, screen_y)
                    self.stamp()

                    walls.append((screen_x, screen_y))

# Create player class to have a player.
class Player(RawTurtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(screen, shape='square')
        self.penup()
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.color('black')

    def bKey(self):
        global color
        print("b key pressed")
        self.color('blue')

    def rKey(self):
        global color
        print("r key pressed")
        self.color('red')

    def gKey(self):
        global color
        print("g key pressed")
        self.color('green')

    def pKey(self):
        global color
        print("p key pressed")
        self.color('purple')

    def yKey(self):
        global color
        print("y key pressed")
        self.color('goldenrod')

    def oKey(self):
        global color
        print("o key pressed")
        self.color('orange')

    # Create setup to create the player on the screen.
    def setup(self, level):
        for y in range(len(level)):
            for x in range(len(level[y])):
                if level[y][x] == 'P':
                    screen_x = (x * 24) - 288
                    screen_y = 288 - (y * 24)

                    self.goto(screen_x, screen_y)

                    return

    # Define a function that will allow player to move up.
    def move_up(self):
        # Calculate the spot to move to.
        movetoX = self.xcor()
        movetoY = self.ycor() + 24

        # Check if the space has a wall.
        if (movetoX, movetoY) not in walls:
            self.goto(movetoX, movetoY)

            gold_encounter()

    # Define a function that will allow player to move down.
    def move_down(self):
        # Calculate the spot to move to.
        movetoX = self.xcor()
        movetoY = self.ycor() - 24

        # Check if the space has a wall.
        if (movetoX, movetoY) not in walls:
            self.goto(movetoX, movetoY)

            gold_encounter()

    # Define a function that will allow player to move left.
    def move_left(self):
        # Calculate the spot to move to.
        movetoX = self.xcor() - 24
        movetoY = self.ycor()

        # Check if the space has a wall.
        if (movetoX, movetoY) not in walls:
            self.goto(movetoX, movetoY)

            gold_encounter()

    # Define a function that will allow player to move right.
    def move_right(self):
        # Calculate the spot to move to.
        movetoX = self.xcor() + 24
        movetoY = self.ycor()

        # Check if the space has a wall.
        if (movetoX, movetoY) not in walls:
            self.goto(movetoX, movetoY)

            gold_encounter()

    # Check if player touches the question.
    def collision(self, other):
        return self.distance(other) < 5

# Create Question class to create the "gold" in the game.
class Question(RawTurtle):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(screen, shape='circle', visible=False)
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.color('hotpink')
        self.penup()
        self.goto(x, y)
        self.showturtle()

    # Define function that will remove gold when collided with.
    def destroy(self):
        self.hideturtle()

# Define function to setup the "gold" in the game.
def setup(level):
    for y in range(len(level)):
        for x in range(len(level[y])):
            char = level[y][x]

            screen_x = -288 + (x * 24)
            screen_y = 288 - (y * 24)

            if char == 'Q':
                questions.append(Question(screen_x, screen_y))

# Define a function for the quit button.
def quitPlaying():
    root.destroy()
    root.quit()

# Game loop in regards to the gold.
def gold_encounter():
    # Check for player collision with a question.
    # Iterate through the questions list.
    for question in questions:
        if player.collision(question):
            infile = open("translations.txt", "r")
            line = infile.readlines()
            ques = line[random.randrange(0, 232)]
            answer = simpledialog.askstring("Input", ques, parent=root)
            # Destroy the question.
            question.destroy()
            # Remove question from questions list.
            questions.remove(question)
            screen.listen()

# Create frame where button(s) will be.
frame = tkinter.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

# Add questions list.
questions = []

# Wall coordinate list.
walls = []

# Create a levels list.
levels = []

# Define first level.
level_1 = [
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XP XXXXXXX          XXXXX",
"X  XXXXXXX  XXXXXX  XXXXX",
"X       XX  XXXXXX  XXXXX",
"X       XX  XXX        XX",
"XXXXXX  XX  XXX   Q    XX",
"XXXXXX  XX  XXXXXX  XXXXX",
"XXXXXX  XX    XXXX  XXXXX",
"X  XXX Q      XXXX  XXXXX",
"X  XXX  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"X         XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"X     Q          XXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXX  X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXX  X",
"XXX  XXXXXXXXXX         X",
"XXX               Q     X",
"XXX         XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXX              X",
"XX   XXXXX        Q     X",
"XX   XXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXX",
"XX    XXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXX",
"XX    Q     XXXX        X",
"XXXX                    X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
]

# Define second level.
level_2 = [
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XP  XX       XX      XXXX",
"X   XX       XX      XXXX",
"X   XXXXXXX  XX  XX     X",
"X   XXXXXXX  XX  XX Q   X",
"X   XX   XX  XX  XXXXX  X",
"X   XX   XX  XX  XXXXX  X",
"XQ         Q     XX  X  X",
"X                XX  X  X",
"X   XXXXXXX   XXXXX  XXXX",
"X   XX   XX             X",
"XXXXXX   XX        Q    X",
"XXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXXXX   X",
"X      Q      XX   XX   X",
"X             XX   XX   X",
"XXXXXXXXXX    XX        X",
"XXXXXX   X    XX     Q  X",
"XXXXXX   X    XX   XX   X",
"X                 X  X  X",
"X       Q         X  X  X",
"XXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXX  X  X",
"XXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXX     X",
"X         X             X",
"X         XQ     XXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
]

# Define third level.
level_3 = [
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"X      X   XP           X",
"X    Q X   X            X",
"X   XXXX   XXXXXXXXXX   X",
"X   XXXX   XXXXXXXXXX   X",
"X         Q    XX       X",
"X              XX       X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXX   XXXX   XXX",
"X              XXXX   XXX",
"X              XXXX   XXX",
"XXXXX Q XXXXXXXXXXX   XXX",
"X                   Q   X",
"X                       X",
"XXXXXXXXXX Q  XXXXXXX   X",
"XXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXX   X",
"XXXX         XXXXXXXXX  X",
"XXX      XXXXXXXXX      X",
"XXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXXXX   X",
"X            X      Q   X",
"X  Q         X       XXXX",
"XXXXXXX            XXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXXXX Q XXXXXXXXXX",
"X                       X",
"X Q         XXX       Q X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
]

# Define fourth level.
level_4 = [
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXX  P  XXXXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXXX Q XXXXXXXXXXX",
"X                       X",
"X          XXX          X",
"XXXXX  Q  XXXXX  Q  XXXXX",
"X          XXX          X",
"XXXXXXXX    X    XXXXXXXX",
"X Q         X         Q X",
"X           X           X",
"XXXXXXXXXX QXQ XXXXXXXXXX",
"X                       X",
"X                       X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   X",
"XXXXXX   XXXXXXXXX      X",
"XXXXXX   XXXXXXX Q  XXXXX",
"XQ                      X",
"X                       X",
"XXXXXXXXXXX   XXXXXXX   X",
"XXXXXXXX      XXXXXXX   X",
"XXXXXX     XXXXXXXXXX   X",
"XXXXX  Q XXXXXXXXXXX Q  X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
]

# Add the level(s) to the levels list.
levels.append(level_1)
levels.append(level_2)
levels.append(level_3)
levels.append(level_4)

# Class instances.
pen = Pen()
player = Player()

# Creation of quit button.
quitButton = tkinter.Button(frame, text='Quit', command=quitPlaying)
quitButton.pack()

# Button commands for player movement
screen.onkeypress(player.move_up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(player.move_down, 'Down')
screen.onkeypress(player.move_left, 'Left')
screen.onkeypress(player.move_right, 'Right')

# Button commands for customizable player colors 
screen.onkeypress(player.bKey, "b")
screen.onkeypress(player.rKey, "r")
screen.onkeypress(player.gKey, "g")
screen.onkeypress(player.pKey, "p")
screen.onkeypress(player.yKey, "y")
screen.onkeypress(player.oKey, "o")

screen.listen()

# Call main game loop.
screen.mainloop()
```

So I expect to be able to ask language-specific questions in each language/level rather than having one language for all the levels. But currently, I'm stuck with a single language for all levels. Please explain it to me as simply as possible.

**EDIT:**
So I've tried the dictionary method and I do not understand what I'm doing wrong. Here is my updated code:

```
from turtle import RawTurtle, TurtleScreen
import tkinter
from tkinter import PhotoImage, simpledialog
import random

largefont = ("Verdana", 12)

# Define function to create Spanish level.
def span():
    pen.setup(level_1)
    player.setup(level_1)
    setup(level_1)

# Define function to create French level.
def fren():
    pen.setup(level_2)
    player.setup(level_2)
    setup(level_2)

# Define function to create Japanese level.
def jpn():
    pen.setup(level_3)
    player.setup(level_3)
    setup(level_3)

# Define function to create Turkish level.
def turk():
    pen.setup(level_4)
    player.setup(level_4)
    setup(level_4)

# Create dictionary.
dic = {'spanish': [
    {'question': 'What is morado/a?', 'answer': 'purple'},
    {'question': 'What is blanco/a?', 'answer': 'white'},
    {'question': 'What is el durazno?', 'answer': 'peach'},
    {'question': 'What is la granada?', 'answer': 'pomegranate'},
    {'question': 'What is la galleta?', 'answer': 'cookie'},
    {'question': 'What is el bistec?', 'answer': 'steak'},
    {'question': 'What is el relámpago?', 'answer': 'lightning'},
    {'question': 'What is el amanecer?', 'answer': 'sunrise'}
],
'french': [
    {'question': 'What is le arc en ciel?', 'answer': 'rainbow'},
    {'question': 'What is la glace?', 'answer': 'ice'},
    {'question': 'What is la cascade?', 'answer': 'waterfall'},
    {'question': 'What is le marais?', 'answer': 'swamp'},
    {'question': 'What is le feu?', 'answer': 'fire'},
    {'question': 'What is la cuillère?', 'answer': 'spoon'},
    {'question': 'What is la bouche?', 'answer': 'mouth'},
    {'question': 'What is le dos?', 'answer': 'back'},
    {'question': 'What is le visage?', 'answer': 'face'},
    {'question': 'What is le chat?', 'answer': 'cat'}
],
'japanese': [
    {'question': 'What is ペンギン?', 'answer': 'penguin'},
    {'question': 'What is 甲虫?', 'answer': 'beetle'},
    {'question': 'What is 蝶々?', 'answer': 'butterfly'},
    {'question': 'What is お兄さん?', 'answer': 'older brother'},
    {'question': 'What is ふうふ?', 'answer': 'married couple'},
    {'question': 'What is 今日は?', 'answer': 'hello'},
    {'question': 'What is 元気です。?', 'answer': 'I am good.'},
    {'question': 'What is わくわくしています。?', 'answer': 'I am excited.'},
    {'question': 'What is 恥ずかしいです。?', 'answer': 'I am embarrassed.'},
    {'question': 'What is 誰??', 'answer': 'Who?'},
    {'question': 'What is 何??', 'answer': 'What?'}
],
'turkish': [
    {'question': 'What is nasıl??', 'answer': 'How?'},
    {'question': 'What is Banyo nerede??', 'answer': 'Where is the bathroom?'},
    {'question': 'What is kitaplık?', 'answer': 'library'},
    {'question': 'What is piyasa?', 'answer': 'market'},
    {'question': 'What is plaj?', 'answer': 'beach'},
    {'question': 'What is fırıncılık?', 'answer': 'bakery'},
    {'question': 'What is kule?', 'answer': 'tower'},
    {'question': 'What is lunapark?', 'answer': 'amusement park'},
    {'question': 'What is taraf?', 'answer': 'party'},
    {'question': 'What is kitapçı?', 'answer': 'bookstore'},
    {'question': 'What is gökdelen?', 'answer': 'skyscraper'},
    {'question': 'What is uçak?', 'answer': 'airplane'},
    {'question': 'What is taksicilik?', 'answer': 'taxi'}
]}

# Create window and canvas using tkinter.
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Language Labyrinth")

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=600, height=600)
canvas.pack()

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
screen.bgcolor('black')

# Define a function to set flag background for Spanish level
def spanishFlag():
    screen.bgpic("spainflag.png")

# Define a function to set flag background for French level
def frenchFlag():
    screen.bgpic("franceflaggrunge.png")

# Define a function to set flag background for Japanese level        
def japaneseFlag():
    screen.bgpic("japanflagoffwhite.png")

# Define a function to set flag background for Turkish level
def turkishFlag():
    screen.bgpic("turkishflagdiagonal.png")

# Define a function to combine the level and background setup functions for Spanish level
def combinedSpanishCommands():
    span()
    spanishFlag()

# Define a function to combine the level and background setup functions for French level
def combinedFrenchCommands():
    fren()
    frenchFlag()

# Define a function to combine the level and background setup functions for Japanese level
def combinedJapaneseCommands():
    jpn()
    japaneseFlag()

# Define a function to combine the level and background setup functions for Turkish level
def combinedTurkishCommands():
    turk()
    turkishFlag()

# Create function to get questions and answers.
def getQuestions(language):
    for qa in dic[language]:
        q = qa.get(question)
        a = qa.get(answer)
        ans = simpledialog.askstring("Input", q, parent=root)
        if ans == a:
            print("Great job!")
        else:
            print("The correct answer was...", a)


# Create function to get Spanish Questions.
def getSpanishQuestions():
    getQuestions('spanish')

# Create function to get French Questions.
def getFrenchQuestions():
    getQuestions('french')

# Create function to get Japanese Questions.
def getJapaneseQuestions():
    getQuestions('japanese')

# Create function to get Turkish Questions.
def getTurkishQuestions():
    getQuestions('turkish')

# Create class with separate window to choose level.
class StartPage():
    def __init__(self):
        # Creation of second window.
        wn = tkinter.Tk()
        wn.title("Welcome!")
        # Creation of game title on start page.
        label = tkinter.Label(wn, text="Language Labyrinth", font=largefont)
        label.pack()

        # Create Spanish level button.
        button = tkinter.Button(wn, text="Spanish", command=combinedSpanishCommands)
        button.pack()

        # Create French level button.
        button2 = tkinter.Button(wn, text="French", command=combinedFrenchCommands)
        button2.pack()

        # Create Japanese level button.
        button3 = tkinter.Button(wn, text="Japanese", command=combinedJapaneseCommands)
        button3.pack()

        # Create Turkish level button.
        button4 = tkinter.Button(wn, text="Turkish", command=combinedTurkishCommands)
        button4.pack()

        # Create quit button for start page.
        qbutton = tkinter.Button(wn, text="Quit", command=wn.destroy)
        qbutton.pack()

start = StartPage()

# Create Pen class to draw the maze.
class Pen(RawTurtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(screen, shape='square')
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.color('white')
        self.penup()

    # Create setup so the maze will be drawn.
    def setup(self, level):
        for y in range(len(level)):
            screen_y = 288 - (y * 24)

            for x in range(len(level[y])):
                if level[y][x] == 'X':
                    screen_x = (x * 24) - 288

                    self.goto(screen_x, screen_y)
                    self.stamp()

                    walls.append((screen_x, screen_y))

# Create player class to have a player.
class Player(RawTurtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(screen, shape='square')
        self.penup()
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.color('black')

    def bKey(self):
        global color
        print("b key pressed")
        self.color('blue')

    def rKey(self):
        global color
        print("r key pressed")
        self.color('red')

    def gKey(self):
        global color
        print("g key pressed")
        self.color('green')

    def pKey(self):
        global color
        print("p key pressed")
        self.color('purple')

    def yKey(self):
        global color
        print("y key pressed")
        self.color('goldenrod')

    def oKey(self):
        global color
        print("o key pressed")
        self.color('orange')

    # Create setup to create the player on the screen.
    def setup(self, level):
        for y in range(len(level)):
            for x in range(len(level[y])):
                if level[y][x] == 'P':
                    screen_x = (x * 24) - 288
                    screen_y = 288 - (y * 24)

                    self.goto(screen_x, screen_y)

                    return

    # Define a function that will allow player to move up.
    def move_up(self):
        # Calculate the spot to move to.
        movetoX = self.xcor()
        movetoY = self.ycor() + 24

        # Check if the space has a wall.
        if (movetoX, movetoY) not in walls:
            self.goto(movetoX, movetoY)

            gold_encounter()

    # Define a function that will allow player to move down.
    def move_down(self):
        # Calculate the spot to move to.
        movetoX = self.xcor()
        movetoY = self.ycor() - 24

        # Check if the space has a wall.
        if (movetoX, movetoY) not in walls:
            self.goto(movetoX, movetoY)

            gold_encounter()

    # Define a function that will allow player to move left.
    def move_left(self):
        # Calculate the spot to move to.
        movetoX = self.xcor() - 24
        movetoY = self.ycor()

        # Check if the space has a wall.
        if (movetoX, movetoY) not in walls:
            self.goto(movetoX, movetoY)

            gold_encounter()

    # Define a function that will allow player to move right.
    def move_right(self):
        # Calculate the spot to move to.
        movetoX = self.xcor() + 24
        movetoY = self.ycor()

        # Check if the space has a wall.
        if (movetoX, movetoY) not in walls:
            self.goto(movetoX, movetoY)

            gold_encounter()

    # Check if player touches the question.
    def collision(self, other):
        return self.distance(other) < 5

# Create Question class to create the "gold" in the game.
class Question(RawTurtle):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(screen, shape='circle', visible=False)
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.color('hotpink')
        self.penup()
        self.goto(x, y)
        self.showturtle()

    # Define function that will remove gold when collided with.
    def destroy(self):
        self.hideturtle()

# Define function to setup the "gold" in the game.
def setup(level):
    for y in range(len(level)):
        for x in range(len(level[y])):
            char = level[y][x]

            screen_x = -288 + (x * 24)
            screen_y = 288 - (y * 24)

            if char == 'Q':
                questions.append(Question(screen_x, screen_y))

# Define a function for the quit button.
def quitPlaying():
    root.destroy()
    root.quit()

# Game loop in regards to the gold.
def gold_encounter():
    if levels[1] == True:
        print("It worked")
        return
    else:
        # Check for player collision with a question.
        # Iterate through the questions list.
        for question in questions:
            if player.collision(question):
                master = tkinter.Tk()
                b1 = tkinter.Button(master, text="Spanish Questions", command=getSpanishQuestions)
                b1.pack()
                b2 = tkinter.Button(master, text="French Questions", command=getFrenchQuestions)
                b2.pack()
                b3 = tkinter.Button(master, text="Japanese Questions", command=getJapaneseQuestions)
                b3.pack()
                b4 = tkinter.Button(master, text="Turkish Questions", command=getTurkishQuestions)
                b4.pack()
                # Destroy the question.
                question.destroy()
                # Remove question from questions list.
                questions.remove(question)
                screen.listen()

# Create frame where button(s) will be.
frame = tkinter.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

# Add questions list.
questions = []

# Wall coordinate list.
walls = []

# Create a levels list.
levels = []

# Define first level.
level_1 = [
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XP XXXXXXX          XXXXX",
"X  XXXXXXX  XXXXXX  XXXXX",
"X       XX  XXXXXX  XXXXX",
"X       XX  XXX        XX",
"XXXXXX  XX  XXX   Q    XX",
"XXXXXX  XX  XXXXXX  XXXXX",
"XXXXXX  XX    XXXX  XXXXX",
"X  XXX Q      XXXX  XXXXX",
"X  XXX  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"X         XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"X     Q          XXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXX  X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXX  X",
"XXX  XXXXXXXXXX         X",
"XXX               Q     X",
"XXX         XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXX              X",
"XX   XXXXX        Q     X",
"XX   XXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXX",
"XX    XXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXX",
"XX    Q     XXXX        X",
"XXXX                    X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
]

# Define second level.
level_2 = [
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XP  XX       XX      XXXX",
"X   XX       XX      XXXX",
"X   XXXXXXX  XX  XX     X",
"X   XXXXXXX  XX  XX Q   X",
"X   XX   XX  XX  XXXXX  X",
"X   XX   XX  XX  XXXXX  X",
"XQ         Q     XX  X  X",
"X                XX  X  X",
"X   XXXXXXX   XXXXX  XXXX",
"X   XX   XX             X",
"XXXXXX   XX        Q    X",
"XXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXXXX   X",
"X      Q      XX   XX   X",
"X             XX   XX   X",
"XXXXXXXXXX    XX        X",
"XXXXXX   X    XX     Q  X",
"XXXXXX   X    XX   XX   X",
"X                 X  X  X",
"X       Q         X  X  X",
"XXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXX  X  X",
"XXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXX     X",
"X         X             X",
"X         XQ     XXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
]

# Define third level.
level_3 = [
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"X      X   XP           X",
"X    Q X   X            X",
"X   XXXX   XXXXXXXXXX   X",
"X   XXXX   XXXXXXXXXX   X",
"X         Q    XX       X",
"X              XX       X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXX   XXXX   XXX",
"X              XXXX   XXX",
"X              XXXX   XXX",
"XXXXX Q XXXXXXXXXXX   XXX",
"X                   Q   X",
"X                       X",
"XXXXXXXXXX Q  XXXXXXX   X",
"XXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXX   X",
"XXXX         XXXXXXXXX  X",
"XXX      XXXXXXXXX      X",
"XXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXXXX   X",
"X            X      Q   X",
"X  Q         X       XXXX",
"XXXXXXX            XXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXXXX Q XXXXXXXXXX",
"X                       X",
"X Q         XXX       Q X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
]

# Define fourth level.
level_4 = [
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXX  P  XXXXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXXX Q XXXXXXXXXXX",
"X                       X",
"X          XXX          X",
"XXXXX  Q  XXXXX  Q  XXXXX",
"X          XXX          X",
"XXXXXXXX    X    XXXXXXXX",
"X Q         X         Q X",
"X           X           X",
"XXXXXXXXXX QXQ XXXXXXXXXX",
"X                       X",
"X                       X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   X",
"XXXXXX   XXXXXXXXX      X",
"XXXXXX   XXXXXXX Q  XXXXX",
"XQ                      X",
"X                       X",
"XXXXXXXXXXX   XXXXXXX   X",
"XXXXXXXX      XXXXXXX   X",
"XXXXXX     XXXXXXXXXX   X",
"XXXXX  Q XXXXXXXXXXX Q  X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
]

# Add the level(s) to the levels list.
levels.append(level_1)
levels.append(level_2)
levels.append(level_3)
levels.append(level_4)

# Class instances.
pen = Pen()
player = Player()

# Creation of quit button.
quitButton = tkinter.Button(frame, text='Quit', command=quitPlaying)
quitButton.pack()

# Button commands for player movement
screen.onkeypress(player.move_up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(player.move_down, 'Down')
screen.onkeypress(player.move_left, 'Left')
screen.onkeypress(player.move_right, 'Right')

# Button commands for customizable player colors 
screen.onkeypress(player.bKey, "b")
screen.onkeypress(player.rKey, "r")
screen.onkeypress(player.gKey, "g")
screen.onkeypress(player.pKey, "p")
screen.onkeypress(player.yKey, "y")
screen.onkeypress(player.oKey, "o")

screen.listen()

# Call main game loop.
screen.mainloop()
```

And then I get this error:

> line 133, in getQuestions
>      q = qa.get(question)
>   NameError: name 'question' is not defined

What am I doing wrong? I don't understand dictionaries very well so I'm at a complete loss.

Comment: Can you give more details about what actually happens when you say "I'm stuck with a single language for all levels"? Also I can't see where you specify a particular language for your questions

Comment: So under the `def gold_encounter():` function, I have a file with vocabulary words that I open and create a list with to ask the question. Right now, all the vocabulary words are randomized under every language. HOWEVER, I want to somehow break it up so that I can have my Spanish words ONLY IN the Spanish level, and my Japanese words ONLY IN the Japanese level, and so on. So I don't get Japanese words in my Spanish levels, for example. I hope that clarified something. It's hard to explain so I'm doing my best to explain it.

Comment: Ok I see. I don't really know turtle or tkinter but from what I see you need something to know in which level you are, like : `if current_level == 'spa': ques = random.choice([l for l in line if is_spanish(l)])` so you need to define `current_level` and `is_spanish`, `is_french` etc

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I perfectly understood your problem, but here is a possible way :

- it looks like your questions are stored somewhere in txt files. The first thing would be, at the the program startup to open those files and to load all the questions in a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for example.
- you could have for the keys the name of the languages you support. Each value would be a list of questions. And Each question would be another dictionary with the question and the anwser.

For example :

```
dic = {
'english' : [
  {'question': 'what is pink ?', 'answer' : 'a pig'},
  {'question': 'what is yellow ?', 'answer' : 'a bird'}
],
'french' : [
...
]
}
```

So now, if you want to loop on the questions of a specific language, you can do :

```
if blabla:
  language = 'english'
else:
  language = 'french'

for qa in dic[language]:
  the_question = qa['question']
  the_answer = qa['answer']
  # continue doing stuff
```

**Edit** : what to put in the if blabla

If you use tkinter, and the user can click on a button to select a language, wrap the above code in a function taking the language as an argument.

```
def getQuestions(language):
  for qa in dic[language]:
    the_question = qa['question']
    the_answer = qa['answer']
    # continue doing stuff
```

You could then create a function for French questions :

```
def getFrenchQuestions():
   getQuestions('French')
```

And bind that function to a button with tkinter :

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
b = Button(master, text="French Questions !", command=getFrenchQuestions)
```

Have a look [there](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm).

And create other buttons for other languages.
If you do that you don't even need the if blabla.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My main problem lies in the `if` statement you have there. What would I put in the `if blabla` statement you have there so that when I click on the French level, for example, it loads the French vocabulary words?

Comment: What he means in this `if blabla` statement is also what I meant in my comment, you need to define in which level/language you currently are somehow, then load the questions with a condition like `if language == 'spanish'`

Comment: i have edited my answer, hopefully it is clearer about that if blabla :)

Comment: @Istopopoki   I thought it was clearer and I tried doing what you said, but honestly I do not understand dictionaries and whatnot very well (which is why I did not try to use a dictionary initially) and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I edited my question with my updated code and the error message I get.

Comment: Sorry, if you want to access a property of the dic, you should do qa['question'], not qa.question as I wrote earlier. My bad. Have a look at examples for how to use a dictionary it is not very complicated. It is just a way to get a value with a key, a little bit like a real dictionary. Also, try to work with a minimal example first, make it work, and then add complexity / features.

Comment: @Istopopoki  Oh, thank you! I got it to work. The only problem is that with the loop, if I scroll over one gold, it loops through all of the questions. Is there a way I can edit it so that it only asks one question per gold in the game? So after it asks one question, I can move onto the next gold for the next question?

Comment: If you don't want to loop over all the questions, you can access only one question. Your questions are stored in an array, so you can access the 3rd french question this way : dic['french'][2]. So you can keep track of the next question you want to ask with a variable and increment it. But please read a little bit of documentation, it will help :)